# How to get column value from excel in JAVA?

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can  i read for each row and cloumn 14 value into string variable in apache poi 4.

```
         while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = rows.next();
                System.out.println(currentRow);
                Iterator<Cell> cellsInRow = currentRow.iterator();
                while(cellsInRow.hasNext()) {
                    Cell currentCell = cellsInRow.next();
                    int cellIndex = currentCell.getColumnIndex();
                    int columnidx = 14;
                    String values = currentCell.getStringValue() //how can i get the  value for every row for column 14  
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Row`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html), you will find the very handy [`getCell(int cellnum)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-) method:

> Get the cell representing a given column (logical cell) 0-based. If you ask for a cell that is not defined....you get a `null`.

Which means you shouldn't iterate all the cells:

```
while (rows.hasNext()) {
    Row currentRow = rows.next();
    Cell cell14 = currentRow.getCell(13); // 14th cell
    String value = (cell14 == null ? null : cell14.getStringCellValue());
    // use value here
}
```

---

Unrelated, but you shouldn't use iterator `while` loops. The code will be simpler and easier to read if you use a for-each loop, so instead of:

```java
Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
while (rows.hasNext()) {
    Row currentRow = rows.next();

    Iterator<Cell> cellsInRow = currentRow.iterator();
    while (cellsInRow.hasNext()) {
        Cell currentCell = cellsInRow.next();

    }
}
```

you should use:

```java
for (Row currentRow : sheet) {

    for (Cell currentCell : currentRow) {

    }
}
```

See how much that improves the code?